# hide links in subsites from quick launch bar

Tags: quick-launch

We have a site in our collection with many subsites, many of which have had links added to their own quick launch bars.

When viewing this parent site, the quick launch bar shows the links under the subsites. How do we turn this off? we want it to show just the subsites as links and nothing else.

We could do this by hiding everything and creating the links manually, but I'd rather new sites be added automatically if possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've worked around this by just using pages; anything that was explicitly linked is now embedded in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the publishing template?  If so on the Navigation page there is an option at the top of the page under Subsites and Pages that allows you to show/hide Subsites and also an option for Pages.  If the links included are the pages, simply uncheck that.

Comment: Yes, it's a publishing site. The pages option is unticked, but the links are being shown because they're not pages - they're links.